# ObjectUtils defaultIfNull returning default value even when first param is not null

Tags: java, java-8

```
target = ObjectUtils.defaultIfNull(getCustomerByAddressID(sourceData, supportParam),
                    createNewCustomer(supportParam));
```

I am passing 2 functions to `ObjectUtils.defaultIfNull`. First is function which returns Customer if found by AddressID else null, second param is function which create new Customer.
After execution I am seeing 2 Customers, debug is showing even after `getCustomerByAddressID(sourceData, supportParam)` returns not null value - `createNewCustomer(supportParam)` is getting executed.

Is this issue because of Code formatting or what am I missing? Should I use `Optional.ofNullable().orElse()` instead of `ObjectUtils.defaultIfNull`?

Comment: `createNewCustomer(supportParam)` is executed because you're calling it when invoking `defaultIfNull`...

Comment: Got it. Thanks @Lino .  I assume same behavior would be for ```Optional.ofNullable(getCustomerByAddressID(sourceData, supportParam)).orElse(createNewCustomer(supportParam))```, isn;t it?

Comment: Exactly, you can use `orElseGet(() -> createNewCustomer(supportParam));` that way it's only executed when it is really needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Optional.ofNullable(getCustomerByAddressID(sourceData, supportParam)).orElseGet(() -> createNewCustomer(supportParam))` if you don't want `createNewCustomer(supportParam)` to be invoked, even if `getCustomerByAddressID(sourceData, supportParam)` is `null`

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
target = Optional.ofNullable(getCustomerByAddressID(sourceData, supportParam))
.orElseGet(() -> createNewCustomer(supportParam));
```

Because both Optional.ofNullable().orElse() and ObjectUtils.defaultIfNull() which uses ternary operator internally, always call "orElse" part.